# Are there dynamo powered front flashing lights?

Tags: headlights, dynamo

I have a bright battery powered front light and I'm looking for a flashing "be seen" front light that's connected to a dynamo so it's always on whenever I ride. Standlight would be ideal, but isn't necessary. I would be connecting it to a bottle dynamo.

I know about all the Reelight options so don't need suggestions of those. I'm also not interested in DIY solutions.

I understand why most dynamo front lights are solid, but am hoping someone knows of a flashing one I just haven't managed to find yet.

Comment: Reason: flashing lights make it harder to judge distance (to the bicycle from the perspective of the car) as well as causing epileptic seizure in a portion of the population.

Comment: You could get a USB hub dynamo, and run a USB powered light.

Comment: @mattnz All the USB bike lights I know of switch off when charging.  Maybe its another regional difference?

Comment: Please, don't do flashing front.

Comment: I'm slightly surprised that https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/18578/are-there-dynamo-powered-rear-flashing-lights doesn't show up as "related". I guess it's because it's closed (for a poor reason, in my opinion; a factual answer is clearly possible, though it would be inherently product specific).

Comment: @armb I did find that one when searching if someone had already asked about front lights. At least everyone has kept opinions to the comments here instead of posting them as answers.

Comment: Experiment shows that a B&M Ixon Core will stay switched on while charging. But it doesn't have a flashing mode, so.... Further experiment shows that an Aldi Bikemate light which _does_ have a flashing mode will also stay on while charging. But that's not widely available. The Lezyne that it looks like a clone of _might_ be the same. https://www.aldi.co.uk/bikemate-front-%26-rear-led-bike-light/p/079057169938700

(I still agree with the people saying "don't do it" though.)

Comment: @armb Thanks for putting in the time to do that research.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Planet Bike Blaze Dynamo has it.

Comment: Flashing fronts are such a bad idea. Don't encourage it. ;)

Comment: RoboKaren @whatsisname The Blaze Dynamo has a pulse mode that fades between 55 and 150 lumens that they refer to as "courtesy flash". Do you have thoughts on pulse modes for front lights compared to flash modes?

Comment: @RoboKaren Why are flashing fronts "such a bad idea"? I see a previous comment mentioning seizures and poor distance judgement.  Is there evidence to support either of these two claims?

Comment: @hmqcnoesy the answer to this question responds partly to your question: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/2294/safety-data-which-is-safer-head-tail-lights-which-blink-or-emit-a-steady-beam